# I can't connect gcp vm windows after excute "netsh advfirewall reset"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, windows-firewall

I connect  using RDP to vm windows in gcp, after in Windows I execute command  `netsh advfirewall reset`
, now I can't connect to my vm.

Please help to connect my vpm, using  configuration in cloud shell or other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this document to [connect to the Windows SAC](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-windows#connect_to_the_windows_sac), then add your RDP firewall rules

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port 3389" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=3389
```

```
netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off
```